# Objects in render view are misplaced

Tags: rendering

The pieces are separated from each other, I use cycles, there is no modifier on them. Origins are in the right position.
In the outliner, the render icon is on. The missing pieces appear under the object. In solid and lookdev mode everything looks fine. In solid mode, I have applied all transform. I did not put any animation on them accidentally. I am using Blender 2.92
Thanks in advance
[image]